# vertical slider in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need vertical slider in java script. The slider should be such that on clicking plus[+] it slides down and on clicking [-] it slides up. The contents are picked from DB and displayed in the screen. I need the slider for the below code.

```
<ck:forEach items="${headings}" var="headings">
  <input type="button" value="<ck:out value="${headings.description}" />"><br>
  <ck:forEach items="${descriptions}" var="descriptions">
        <ck:if test="${headings.identifier == descriptions.identifier}">                    
                <ul><li><ck:out value="${descriptions.text}" /></li></ul>                   
        </ck:if>
  </ck:forEach>
        <br>
</ck:forEach>
```

I cannot use JQuery plugins.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#simple-vertical').royalSlider({
    arrowsNav: true,
    arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
    fadeinLoadedSlide: true,
    controlNavigation: 'none',
    imageScaleMode: 'fill',
    imageAlignCenter:true,
    loop: false,
    loopRewind: false,
    numImagesToPreload: 4,
    slidesOrientation: 'vertical',
    keyboardNavEnabled: true,
    video: {
      autoHideArrows:true,
      autoHideControlNav:true
    },  

    autoScaleSlider: true, 
    autoScaleSliderWidth: 960,     
    autoScaleSliderHeight: 850,

    /* size of all images http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/royalslider-jquery-plugin-faq/adding-width-and-height-properties-to-images */
    imgWidth: 640,
    imgHeight: 360
  });
});
```

[DEMO PAGE](https://www.anglehouseorthodontics.co.uk/gallery/templates/simple-vertical/)